# Open android application when device opens

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an android application that I want that starts when the device is opened and remains on foreground until it is closed. To achieve this I have used some tricks that I found surfing the Internet:

- Start application when device starts >> Solved using a broadcast receiver that handles the   *android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED*
- Ignore the Home button when the application is opened >> Solved using an Activity Alias that is installed when the app starts and uninstalled when the application closes

I test the solution and it works fine almost always. When I close the device with the app executing and it restarts the device the application is opened twice. I think that the *extra* opening is due because the Activity Alias wasn't uninstalled because the app doesn't close properly when I shutdown the device.

Is there a solution to avoid this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use  **ACTION_SHUTDOWN** and perform necessary task on shutdown.Find more details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN).

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use the Shutdown intent to finish your activity when the device is shutting down.

```
<receiver android:name=".myReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then you can just use the `activity.finish();` to close your app.